# How to render multiple dimensional array data in section list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an array of objects like

```
MainArray[
 {date:xyz,
  events:[
          {
            time:2pm,
            events[
                    {
                       eventID:2931,
                       starttime:2,
                       end time:4
                     },
                    { multiple similar object}    
                   ]         
             }
          }
]
```

Something like this structure ,Now I want to reder them in a flat list but i can't understand what should I pass in section. I want to access all key  like eventId ,start,end of all object.
There can be multiple object like this based on time and date.
Than you any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Are you trying to render  a  list of all events with all dates ?

Comment: I want to render all events with different time under different section